# Aspect ratio based on 100% height

Tags: html, css

I'm fighting with this for too long now and could need some help.
I have a container wrapper with a fixed height.
Inside is another container with a header and div. This div `ratio_div` should have the maximum available height while maintaining a ratio of 16/9.

[image]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Markus-Rappat/pen/LYMEvgX)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
.container_inner {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-block: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.header {
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.ratio_div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="container_inner">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="ratio_div"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post HTML and the rest of the CSS as a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried looking through CSS documentation? [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) could help you.

Comment: I’m not sure I fully understand. In the picture you show, a portrait orientation, if the height is 100% (% of what?) and the aspect ratio 16/9 won’t the div be too wide?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** After a bit of thinking, I managed to find a more universal answer. Without set rigid sizing:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  margin: 0;
}

.container_inner {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  column-gap: 1rem;
}

.ratio_div {
  border: 1px dotted;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_inner">
 <div class="header">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
 </div>
 <div class="ratio_div"></div>
</div>
```

Old answer: <del>Need to know `height` of `.header` and `gap` in `.container_inner`:</del>

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.container_inner {
  --header-height: 2rem;
  --gap: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-block: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: var(--header-height);
}

.ratio_div {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: calc(100% - var(--header-height) - var(--gap));
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_inner">
 <div class="header">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
 </div>
 <div class="ratio_div"></div>
</div>
```